# Computing $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2-\sin x}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: complex-analysis

> I want to compute
> $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2-\sin x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

I used residues and integrated over the unit circle, arriving at a final answer of $-\pi/2$. Is this right? I'm afraid I made a mistake somewhere in the factorisation of the denominator.

After factorizing, my function became $-1/(z+2i+\sqrt{3i})(z+2i-\sqrt{3i})$.

Only one pole lies within $C$, namely $(2-\sqrt3)i$, so we consider its residue, which got me to $-2\pi i \cdot (1/4i) = -\pi/2$.

Comment: If you want your calculation critiqued, you need to show the calculation.

Comment: If you integrate a positive function, you cannot get a negative answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your integrand is incorrect. Express $\sin x$ in terms exponentials:

$$\frac1{2-\sin x}=\frac1{2-\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}}=\frac{2ie^{ix}}{1+4ie^{ix}-e^{2ix}}$$

Now substitute $z=e^{ix}$ and $\mathrm dz=ie^{ix}\,\mathrm dx$, and interpret the integral over $0\le x\le2\pi$ as a line integral over unit circle $|z|=1$ in the complex plane.

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm dx}{2-\sin x}=\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{2iz}{1+4iz-z^2}\frac{\mathrm dz}{iz}=\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{2}{(z-(2-\sqrt3)i)(z-(2+\sqrt3)i)}\,\mathrm dz$$